# Why do I get a segmentation fault here

Tags: c

Excuse me for the sloppy code, I am still a beginner. But after putting a long time into this programming question I got from my Uni I don't know where to turn.

The question itself is: we need to read from the "staedte.csv" (which displays the population and cities of German states) and then return an array of strings with the strings formatted like this: The city ***** has a population of ****.

You are supposed to pass in 2 arguments into the cli: the number 100 and the state you want to check the cities and population for: example Bayern (Bavaria).

My plan was to make a 2d array. First I would dynamically allocate the memory for the first one by making a for loop and iterating over the original csv to check how many states in the csv = the state from the arguments. Then I would make a dynamic array using the amount of states in the csv matching. Then I would iterate (with for loop) over the list of matching states and then first check the length of the formatted string then: The city ***** has a population of ****., then allocate that memory and store the pointer to that info in the previously created array. Then I try to print the first item of that array, meaning the pointer.

I checked and there are 8 elements in the csv with Bavaria as their state, but in the for loop

```
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
```

if j is larger than 4 then I Get a segmentation fault even though the space is supposed to be allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "input3.h"

/* Die Konstanten:
 *  int MAX_LAENGE_STR - die maximale String Länge
 *  int MAX_LAENGE_ARR - die maximale Array Länge
 *  sind input3.c auf jeweils 255 und 100 definiert
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Aufruf: %s <anzahl> <bundesland>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s 100 Bayern\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Klein-/Großschreibung beachten!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // int anzahl = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *bundesland = argv[2];

    // Statisch allokierter Speicher
    char staedte[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    char laender[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    int bewohner[MAX_LAENGE_ARR];

    read_file("staedte.csv", staedte, laender, bewohner);

    // printf("%s   %s", bundesland, laender[5]);
    int CityCounter = 0;
    int CopyCounter = 0;
    int *CityArray;
    CityArray = (int *)malloc(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LAENGE_ARR; i++)
    {
        if (strncmp(laender[i], bundesland, strnlen(bundesland, 10)) == 0)
        {

            CityArray = realloc(CityArray, sizeof(CityArray) + sizeof(int) * 1);
            CityArray[CityCounter] = i;
            CityCounter++;
        }
    }
    // printf("%d", CityCounter);
    char **string = (char **)malloc(CityCounter * sizeof(int));
    int j;
    printf("%d", (int)sizeof(CityArray));
    int numOfCities = (int)sizeof(CityArray);
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        char buffer[100];
        size_t size = snprintf(buffer, 50, "Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner.\n", staedte[CityArray[j]], bewohner[CityArray[j]]);
        string[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
        // string[j][size] = "\0";
        strncpy(string[j], buffer, size);
    }
    // printf("%s", string[2]);
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfCities; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", string[i]);
    }
    // write_file(string, sizeof(string));

    free(string);
}
```

this is the code I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "input3.h"

int MAX_LAENGE_STR = 255;
int MAX_LAENGE_ARR = 100;

void write_file(char *result[], int len)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("resultat.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("resultat.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", result[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int read_file(char *dateiname, char staedte[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], char laender[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], int bewohner[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(dateiname, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror(dateiname);
        exit(1);
    }

    char stadt[MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    char land[MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    int anzahl;
    int i = 0;
    int len;

    while (fscanf(fp, "\"%[^\"]\";\"%[^\"]\";%d\n", stadt, land, &anzahl) != EOF)
    {
        if (i >= MAX_LAENGE_ARR)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Die Datei ist größer als erwartet!");
            return i;
        }
        len = strlen(stadt) + 1;
        strncpy(staedte[i], stadt, len - 1);
        staedte[i][len - 1] = '\0';

        len = strlen(land) + 1;
        strncpy(laender[i], land, len - 1);
        laender[i][len - 1] = '\0';

        bewohner[i] = anzahl;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}
```

```
extern int MAX_LAENGE_ARR;
extern int MAX_LAENGE_STR;

void write_file(char *result[], int len);
int read_file(char *dateiname, char staedte[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], char laender[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], int bewohner []);
```

This code was supplied by our Uni but it should be correct.

---

So I changed the
char **string = (char **)malloc(CityCounter * sizeof(int)); to  char

**string = (char **)malloc(CityCounter * sizeof(char*)); and now I don't get null.
But if I once again change the
for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {}
and modify the j larger then 4 then I get a bus error

Comment: The `sizeof(CityArray)` does not give its length (only the pointer size). You must keep track of that.

Comment: However when I printed that it gave me back the length. So I just used that. I don't think that is where the problem is

Comment: Fix the formatting of the post please

Comment: @Schageus "I don't think that is where the problem is" You are mistaken. There is more than one problem, but this one is definitely **a** problem.

Comment: In this line char **string = (char **)malloc(CityCounter * sizeof(int)); why you are using size of int, you are creating a array of char* pointers, you should use char **string = (char **)malloc(CityCounter * sizeof(char*));

Comment: @amirhm I changed that whole thing to sizeof(*char). I have no idea why I first had int there

Comment: @Schageus now it is fixed your  segmentation problem?